# Unable to convert the row into Colum in PDF doc using UniPDF

Tags: go, pdf

I am trying to convert the row of a PDF table in a column using UniPDF Go Library, I have tried the example they are mentioned at https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/blob/master/tables/pdf_tables_row_wrap.go but I am not able to modify the document as required.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand this correctly, but I am assuming you have input data that you want to display in a single column.

To achieve this, you can create a single-cell column:
https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/blob/fe269eb0efffed8e199c82cb7b7b4a38859b35d7/tables/pdf_tables_simple.go#L98
with

```
table := c.NewTable(1)
```

I have created a play for this: https://play.unidoc.io/p/3421387bcde00a52

see also
https://apidocs.unidoc.io/unipdf/v3.20.0/github.com/unidoc/unipdf/v3/creator/#Creator.NewTable

Comment: Thank you @Gunnsteinn Hall, It really helps and worked as expected.